# PHP downloading files has been corrupted(While downloading from ftp server)

Tags: php, upload

I have problem in downloading file(php)from a particular folder.

when i download and open the file it says your file is corrupted.

when i check the size of the uploaded file and downloaded file it is same , but      for zip file size it differs.

No Files are opening.

can any one say where i am wrong???

```
if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
  $filename = $_GET['file'];
} 
else
{
  $filename = NULL;
}

$err = 'Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable.';
if (!$filename) {
// if variable $filename is NULL or false display the message
  echo $err;
} 
else 
{
// define the path to your download folder plus assign the file name
  $path = '/public_html/wp-content/uploads/'.$filename;
// check that file exists and is readable
  if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
// get the file size and send the http headers
    $size = filesize($path);
    header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
// open the file in binary read-only mode
// display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
    $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
    if ($file) {
// stream the file and exit the script when complete
      fpassthru($file);
      exit;
    } else {
      echo $err;
    }
  } else {
    echo $err;
  }

  exit;

}
```

inserting into table:

```
 echo "<tr><td><a href='?file=" . $row["FileupName"]. "'>".$row["FileupName"]."</td></tr>";
```

I am happy that the file is getting downloaded but it not getting opened.

.txt file is getting opened.

Had checked with header also.

i have tried putting:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (file_exists($path)) {

                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($path));
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($path);
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: @Bekri it's not getting downloaded....please can i know where exactly to place the code....which part of my code (above ) should be replaced

Comment: No Bekir its not downloading, but in url i am getting the file name.

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, posting solid code blocks without any explanation serves no educational purpose. Please improve your answer by explaining why this code is a solution or if it is based on OP's what has changed and for what reason.

Comment: @Bekir same issue corrupted

Comment: You make file encoding utf-8